# Docker container shows no ports, can find IP but need both to connect to Java application

Tags: java, docker, containers, ip, port

So I'm fairly new to Docker, only been using it for a day or two and recently pulled this https://hub.docker.com/r/ncbi/blast
Which is an image that has a set of commands to get information from a database. I have the Desktop version of Docker for windows and manage to get the image to pop up just fine. It shows up in my images,
[image]
[image]
I run the image via the desktop app. Give it the name "Test", see it's running using the "docker ps". I get it's IP just fine but see there are no ports.
[image]
I've heard that it might be connected to my local host which is why no ports show up but still where would I go to find my host port then and or just change the port? A java program/application I'm making is supposed to connect to this using IP and Port but I can't find the port. Any help would be appreciated, thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include `-p` flag in your `docker run` command to expose ports for your application.

`-d` options runs docker container in the [background](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d).

For e.g. In [Docker Run Command](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d ncbi/blast:latest
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done so and now have a new container on the Docker desktop app but when I try to run it via the Desktop app I get nothing. Nothing starts for some reason. I go to "docker ps" and see no container is running either. I do the "container start "container name"" and get back my container name but still see nothing pop up when I do "docker ps". Is this normal?

Comment: Now I also get the issue where when I can't seem to find any connected IP address to this either. I run docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' "container ID" and get nothing back. Does it have anything to with the -d?

Comment: `-d` only runs the docker container in the background. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d

Comment: Paste your `docker ps` output